# Tor TLS cipher suite negotiation and fingerprint defense

Tags: pluggable-transports, fingerprinting, tls

In reading this [bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/4744) I can see that, in the past, Tor has been fingerprinted based on the cipher suites negotiated in the initial TLS handshake. Originally it looks like a copy of the cipher suites in a version of Firefox negotiating with Apache were used -- the goal being that it mimics a standard browser. The result of the bug was that the cipher suite was updated to look like other browsers.

My questions are:

- How effective is this solution? The [pluggable transports page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/AChildsGardenOfPluggableTransports) shows why this isn't perfect, but is there any information on whether it's currently being used to block connections?
- While a variety of suites are offered only a few can actually be used by Tor. Would a plausible active attack exist where an adversary could force force negotiation using an unsupported cipher in order to verify the host is a Tor node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, Tor is moving away from looking like TLS, with pluggable transports being the solution for censored users. Tor is moving to using stronger cryptographic primitives so looking like a browser is no longer the goal. Detecting Tor relays not behind pluggable transports is relatively straightforward. One of the ways is doing what you describe.